# OTA good practice: prevent "without OTA" updates

Tags: iot, esp8266, esp32, ota

I am using an `esp32`, with the function [esp_https_ota](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/esp_https_ota.html), but i think the situation applies in any iot OTA.

Let's take the situation:

- I release a release whose firmware badly controls subsequent OTAs
- I would like to release a patch ... but I can't because I broke the OTAs

Are there any tools or best practices to address this?

NB: I am not looking for a "solution", I do not want to remedy a problem that has already occurred, I would simply like to understand good practices.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to work with a beta release; in my devices you can choose a firmware location; the regular and a beta/test location. Last only for devices in reach of course. Will prevent most of the problems.

And the function you intend to I guess is the app rollback function. Although it has some possible security issues, if you run the program and let it do some easy tasks to verify basic function and consequently validate the image, 99% of your problems is solved.

To tackle the last percent I added OTA over SD, so people can put a firmware image on sd card. In my opinion wifi/https takes a lot of buts and ifs to work.